# Why their data seem to be synchronous?

Tags: javascript

In javascript, when I

```
var buffer = new Array();
buffer = AnotherArray;
```

but it is strange that what I did to buffer, turn out it happens to AnotheArray too. For example, I have delete some elements in buffer and I found that they re also deleted in AnotherArray. Why is that and How can I solve it?

Comment: Welcome to the world of reference types!

Answer (score 4):

Your code, as quoted, absolutely does not cause the array created by `new Array()` on the first line and `AnotherArray` on the next line to be related in any way. If you're seeing some kind of effect between them, it lies in code you haven't quoted.

Specifically, your code creates an array and then completely throws it away, having `buffer` refer to a *different* thing (which, from the name, seems like it might be an array). But the array created in the first line is lost.

I suspect you might be doing something like this:

```
var buffer = new Array();
var foo = new Array();
buffer = foo;
buffer.push("Testing");
alert(foo.length); // alerts "1", not "0"
```

In that case, the array created on the first line is completely thrown away, and (on the third line) you point both `buffer` and `foo` at the **same** array. There's only one array, but you have two references to it. So anything you do via the `buffer` reference to the array, you also see when you look at that same array via the `foo` reference. There's only one array, you just have two references to it.

If you want to *copy* the array, see (a long way) below under the dividing line.

If you think about it, it's exactly like what happens when you pass a reference into a function:

```
var f = new Array(); // Or better, you could use `[]` rather than `new Array()`
f.push("one");
bar(f);
alert(f.length);     // alerts "2"

function bar(a) {
    a.push("two");   // Here, `a` and `f` point to the **same** array
}
```

There, the alert shows "2" rather than "1" because the code in the `bar` function added to the array, via the `a` reference in its argument list, which pointed to the same array as the `f` reference.

JavaScript has object types (aka reference types) and primitives. Strings and numbers are primitives, they're actually held within the memory assigned to a variable. Just about everything else is an object, where the variable holds a *reference* to the object, not a copy of the object itself. So:

```
var a = 1;
var b = a;
b = 2;
alert(a); // "1"
alert(b); // "2"
```

`a` and `b` have *copies* of the primitive number `1`. But:

```
var c = {prop: "value"};
var d = c;
d.prop = "updated value";
alert(c.prop); // "updated value"
```

There, `c` and `d` point to the **same** object, so changes to the object are evident regardless of which reference to it (`c` or `d`) you look at it with.

And of course:

```
var e = {prop: "foo"};
var f = {prop: "foo"};
f.prop = "bar";
alert(e.prop); // "foo"
```

Since `e` and `f` point to *different* objects, changes to one have no effect on the other.

The key to keeping this straight is to think of a *reference* (not an object) as being a primitive value. A *reference* is just an arbitrary thing that lets you look up the object in a table. So while this:

```
var a = 1;
```

...yields this in memory:

```
+-------+
|   a   |
+-------+
|   1   |
+-------+
```

...this:

```
var c = {prop: "value"};
```

...yields this:

```
+-------+
|   c   |
+-------+              +---------------+
|  ref  |------------->| prop: "value" |
+-------+              +---------------+
```

Consequently, this:

```
var a = 1;
var b = a;
```

...yields:

```
+-------+
|   a   |
+-------+
|   1   |
+-------+

+-------+
|   b   |
+-------+
|   1   |
+-------+
```

...but this:

```
var c = {prop: "value"};
var d = c;
```

...yields this:

```
+-------+
|   c   |
+-------+
|  ref  |----\
+-------+    |
             |
             |       +---------------+
             |------>| prop: "value" |
             |       +---------------+
+-------+    |
|   d   |    |
+-------+    |
|  ref  |----/
+-------+
```

The *reference* is what the variables hold, not the object. References are primitives that point to objects.

---

So what do you do about it? Well, most of the time, this is what you want, because most of the time you want to pass references around and refer back to the original object. But sometimes you want to actually *copy* an object.

With arrays, that's easy: Use [`Array#slice`](http://es5.github.com/#x15.4.4.10) passing in `0` for the first argument and no second argument:

```
var a = [1, 2, 3];  // An array containing 1, 2, and 3
alert(a.length);    // "3"
var b = a.slice(0); // Copy it
alert(b.length);    // "3"
b.push(4);          // Add a fourth element
alert(b.length);    // "4", it *has* changed
alert(a.length);    // "3", it hasn't changed
```

`Array#slice` creates a new array and *copies* elements from the source array to it, starting with the element you specify. Since we're saying `0`, it copies the whole array. Note that it's a *shallow* copy, if any of the array entries is a reference to an object, just as with `a = b;`, the *reference* is copied, not the object.

Comment: You actually pass a value (value being an array pointer) to the function, there is no passing references in javascript. But +1 as always :p

Comment: @Esailija: Yes, exactly. References *are* values (primitive values that point to objects in memory).

Comment: Yeah but saying `pass a reference to a function` implies that you pass a reference to the function instead of a value. But in javascript it is in fact copied and not passed by reference. I.E. the local variable `a` inside function `bar` is a copy of the passed argument `f` and is not a reference to `f`, even if `f` is a reference primitive. `a` would be a reference to `f` if you could change the value `f` holds inside the function but you can't: `f` will remain a reference to the array no matter what you do to `a` inside the function. So it is not passed by reference. That's what I meant :P

Comment: @Esailija: I understand, but the key is this (and I say this later in the answer): Object references **are** values. This is key to really understanding what's going on. An object reference is a primitive value (say, 23174328), which is used to look up an object in memory somewhere. We can't see the raw value of them, but that's what they are. And like all other primitive values, they're copied when they're moved around (copied from variable to variable, passed into functions, etc.), *exactly* like numbers. The ref isn't the object, it's just something that lets us locate the object.

Comment: @Newbie: If you want to make a *copy* of an array, you can use `var copy = original.slice(0);` I've updated the answer to show that.

Answer (score 1):

`buffer` is a reference to `AnotherArray`, a different name for the same object in memory.

It is like refering to a person using a full name or a nick name - both ways can be used to 'access' a person instance.

Answer (score 1):

That occours because that way the two variables point to the same array.
To avoid this, if you want to assign a copy of `AnotherArray` to `buffer`, you can use `slice()`:

```
var buffer = AnotherArray.slice();
```

Answer (score 0):

Several things are happening...

```
var buffer = new Array(); // A new, empty array is created. It is
                          // accessed via buffer

buffer = AnotherArray;    // Remember that new array that buffer pointed to?
                          // It's now gone, and will be garbage collected.
                          //
                          // Now buffer is a second reference to AnotherArray.
                          // Any changes to AnotherArray are now also changes
                          // to buffer. Both buffer and AnotherArray are
                          // references to a single array in memory.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var buffer = new Array();
```

Creates a new array and makes `buffer` point to it.

```
buffer = AnotherArray;
```

Makes `buffer` point to the array that `AnotherArray` is pointing to, so `buffer` and `AnotherArray` point to the same array. This is by design since most of the time you don't want to go through the trouble of copying an object (or especially a function), which is a huge waste of memory.